# Crear y usar componente en angular

Tags: angular

estoy empezando con angular y estoy intentando crear un componente. En primer lugar lo he creado en la carpeta app dentro de otra llamada header con el nombre reader.component.ts, cuyo contenido es:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    template: `
    <h1>Probando angular</h1>
    `
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

Después lo he cargado en el app.module.ts así

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

y en el index.html he quitado el componente  y he añadido el mío:

```
<body>
  <!-- <app-root></app-root> -->
  <app-header></app-header>
</body>
```

Pero la página de resultado no muestra, nada. Entonces, por qué no me muestra el componente?

Comment: haz agregado este componente en tu app.module o el que tengas como componente padre?

Answer (score 0):

Al que se le está aplicando el "bootstrap" en el AppModule es al AppComponent (etiqueta `<app-root></app-root>`)

entonces en el index.html tienes que dejar el app-root y dentro del app.component.html tienes que agregar la etiqueta `<app-header></app-header>`

o bien en el AppModule en la sección "bootstrap" usas el HeaderComponent y en el index.html usas la etiqueta `<app-header></app-header>`

cualquiera de las 2 formas te debería funcionar

PD: la propiedad bootstrap ciertamente es un array pero esta pensado solo usar 1 componente raiz y dentro de ese utilizar todos los demás, si quieres hacer multiple componentes en el "bootstrap" hay que hacer un poco mas de trabajo pero usualmente no tiene sentido hacer eso, usar la forma de 1 componente raiz es suficiente es como considerar este componente raiz tu nuevo "body"